# Capybara: Cannot find element

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, cucumber, capybara

I am using capybara to click a checkbox, however it can't seem to find it no matter what I do. I am able to correctly find both the span and the label inside the span, but not the input I actually need.

Here is the checkbox

```
<span class="checkbox tos">
  <input id="agreement" name="agreement" onclick="agreeValidate();" type="checkbox" value="false">
  <label for="agreement">I accept the <a href="http://www.dev.com:3000/terms" target="_blank">Terms of Use</a>, <a href="http://www.dev.com:3000/privacy" target="_blank">Privacy Policy</a>, and am at least 13 years old</label>
</span>
```

And here is some of the things I have tried

```
page.check('agreement')
find(:css, '#agreement').set(true)
find('#agreement').set(true)
find('#agreement').click
```

However, they all give me the same error

```
Unable to find css "#agreement" (Capybara::ElementNotFound)
```

I also am wondering will any of these methods fire off the `onclick` method, when the checkbox is clicked? I feel like `find(:css, '#agreement').set(true)` will not trigger the `onclick` event. However, I am not sure about the rest.

EDIT**
I have also tried selecting the element through xpath. Here are the various things I have found out

```
find(:xpath, '//*[@id="registration"]/span[2]')
```

This is able to find the `span` element no problem

```
find(:xpath, '//*[@id="registration"]/span[2]/input')
```

This cant find the element I need, but this xpath correctly selects the element in chromes console

```
find(:xpath, '//*[@id="agreement"]')
```

This cant find the element I need, but the xpath selects the element in chromes console

```
find(:xpath, '//*[@id="registration"]/span[2]/label')
```

This is able to find the `label` element in the `span` with no problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the cheatsheet for Capybara here: http://learn.thoughtbot.com/test-driven-rails-resources/capybara.pdf

It's a bad idea to interact with form through CSS. A better way to do something like this:

```
check 'I accept cool agreement'
click_button 'Submit'
```

So you do not need to know ID of element or class. Just use what users can see on page.

Comment: Could you justify your opinion (with examples/reasons) for why it is a bad idea to interact with a form through classes/ids? At least in my experience, these are much less likely to change than the text of the question.